# Cannot deploy a simple war-file to Glassfish 4

Tags: glassfish

In the beginning I have to admit that I am very new to Glassfish server.

I have a very simple war-file (helloworld.war) which contains only one html-file (index.html): https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/69838986/helloworld.war.

I can deploy it to GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.0, but when I call http://localhost:8080/helloworld/index.html I get only a blank page. "View source" on this page is also blank.

I deployed the war-file in 2 ways:
-I put it in the autodeploy-folder. The file "helloworld.war_deployed" is generated.
-Commandline: asadmin deploy "C:\Temp\helloworld.war". Result: Application deployed with name helloworld. Command deploy executed successfully.

Any idea why my index.html doesn't come up?

Regards,
Steffen

Answer (score 0):

your application seems to be correct and I was able to deploy it ok. I would investigate following:

- look into glassfish/domains/domain1/logs/server.log in your Glassfish installation and check if there are no errors - attach any error you find, please
- check if your administration console works: http://localhost:4848, user is by default "admin" with no password
- try to deploy using console from browser, navigate to the application and launch it
- check network communication using development tools in the browser, I would look for response headers and result code

Comment: Did you get a proper result when calling index.html? I only get a blank file. However I found out that everything works well if I place an empty WEB-INF/web.xml file in my war-archive. Why is that? I would have supposed that this should work without such a file.

Comment: Thank you @StSch !   You helped me around the same problem.